# jQuery Snap/Fixed Menu Width Changes and Jumps When Scrolled Past Certain Point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-position

I have a horizontal nav I'd lock fixed to the top of the page when the nav's top property is at the top of the page. However, when the nav reaches the top of the page, it increases its width and is jumpy. Once I've scrolled down a little further, this phenomenon stops. Note that this same thing happens when scrolling back up. In other words, as the top of the nav reaches the top of the page, the width-change-jumpiness thing occurs.

Link to fiddle below. I tried to add the code as best I could, but SO is complaining about it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc2ojqjw/2/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="phone-number">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="phone-sub-text">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="social-media">
        <div>
            <img id="fb-icon" src="img/fb-rect.jpg"/>
            <img src="img/twitter-rect.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>
    ...
    </h1>
        <div id="float-nav-bar"></div>
        <div id="main">
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
            <header class="sub-header">
                ...
            </header>
            <div id="main-content-top" class="main-content">
                <section>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                </section>
                <figure>
                    <img src="#" />
                </figure>
            </div>
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
            <header class="sub-header">
                ...
            </header>
            <div id="main-content-bottom" class="main-content">
                <section>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...
                    <br/>
                    ...                    
                </section>
                <figure>
                    <img src="#">
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="container-footer">

        </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var topOfNav = $('#float-nav-bar').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > topOfNav){ 

            $('#float-nav-bar').addClass('fixed');
        }
        else 
        {

            $('#float-nav-bar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
}

h1, h2, h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 36pt;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 a {
    color: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

header {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 20pt;
    color: rgb(0, 64, 135);
}

.container-footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 137, 96);
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
}

#float-nav-bar {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Can you try setting a fixed width for `#float-nav-bar` like `width: 250px;` rather than using `%` ? Or you _need_ to use `%` ?

Comment: I'd like it to inherit from its parent container. That doesn't fix the jumpiness thing anyway, which is far more pressing to me. I have a few "fixes" for the width thing, but I'd like to see where fixing the jumpiness thing takes me first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jumpiness is a classic case of the changing-height-in-scroll-event debacle. Making the nav bar `position: fixed` when scrolling takes that element out of the normal document flow, reducing the height of the document, which scrolls the document back up, which kicks the nav bar back to normal positioning. You're still scrolling this whole time, so the cycle runs repeatedly, leading to the jumping. The fix is fairly easy: insert a placeholder that will fill that space when the nav bar is fixed.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-bar-placeholder" class="float-nav-bar"></div>
<div id="float-nav-bar" class="float-nav-bar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.float-nav-bar {
    height: 100px;
}

#float-nav-bar {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

#nav-bar-placeholder {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > topOfNav){ 
        $('#nav-bar-placeholder').show();
        $('#float-nav-bar').addClass('fixed');
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#nav-bar-placeholder').hide();
        $('#float-nav-bar').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

See this JSFiddle for a complete working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wdgcbnkm/.

Comment: Fan. Freakin'. Tastic! Thank you, kind sir. Is there any way to have class .float-nav-bar have a height of inherit (or similar)? I'd rather not set the height explicitly, but if that's what has to be done, so be it. I naturally tried inherit, but it was a no go.

Comment: @Gregolopolis You probably could wrap both the nav bar and placeholder in a container div and have them both inherit. Best of luck!